# is there a markup language for graphs?

Tags: xml

Is there a commonly used markup language for graphs (the topological kind). I would expect XMLelements such as Node and Edge and attributes showing directionality and labels

UPDATE:
So far there is a choice of 2, GraphML and DotML. GraphML hasn't changed since 2007 but maybe it doesn't need to! SO readers may wish to know what toolsets each have - I am encouraged that Gephi uses GrahML, and obviously DotML has the GraphViz and other toolsets. (I shall be writing a limited toolkit in Java for whichever language I choose)

UPDATE: 
I am personally going with DotML. I need the language for modelling (e.g. adding labels, weights, etc. to nodes and edges so will need my own additional namespace). The attraction of DotML is that it seems to be active, and that graphViz can make use of the output. YMMV

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Dot language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language) is the main language I've used for graphs.

This language is used by systems such as GraphViz to generate its graphs and is fairly human readable.

Here's the [graphviz DOT language reference](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html).

As an aside note, I wrote a .NET GraphViz wrapper that can be used to parse DOT strings and output graphs. If that's something of use to you then you can grab the code from CodePlex: http://graphviz.codeplex.com/

Comment: There is an XML-encoded version of DOT called DotML, which I use for preparing diagrams in the XSLT specification.

Comment: Sorry - edited this entry by mistake and then deleted my additions

Answer (score 2):

A useful tool, using a variant of the GraphML descriptions, is yEd (http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html). I've used it for visualizing simple graphs. It's markup language IMHO is more like XML. They have a library to use in your applications, but I've never used it.

Answer (score 1):

Not a markup in the XML sense, but you can use the [Dot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language) language.  Programs like [graphviz](http://graphviz.org/) will take Dot output and turn it into a pretty graph.  As pointed out in the comments, there is also [DotML](http://martin-loetzsch.de/DOTML/).

If you want XML based, then [GraphML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphML), [DGML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DGML) and [GXL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GXL) exist, but I've never come across them in practical applications!

Comment: There is an XML-encoded version of DOT called DotML, which I use for preparing diagrams in the XSLT specification.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks, hadn't seen that before.  Edited the answer to add it.